# avoiding arg0 tag

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, ejb-3.0

I am using EJB3 webservice and Jaxb. No where in my input xsd I have metioned an element arg0. But its getting created when I open the WSDL in my SOAP UI. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think getting arg0, arg1 is a JAXWS specification. If we want to customize it we have to use @WebParam and @WebResult annotations to specify nice names. If someone can validate this understanding it would be great.

Comment: What is the parameter is actually a java object (i.e. complext object from jaxb's POV) ? How can I give names to the object's members ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, in my SOAP request the body was getting wrapped inside an arg0 element. The solution was to use the annotation

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```

as the default value is

```
SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED
```

due to which the SOAP body gets wrapped in an arg0 element.
The web service interface looks like

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = WSInterface.NAMESPACE_REQUEST)
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface WSInterface{
  String NAMESPACE_REQUEST = "...";

  String NAMESPACE_RESPONSE = "...";

  String TARGET_OPERATION = "...";

  String RESULT_ELEMENT = "...";

  @WebMethod(operationName = TARGET_OPERATION)
  @WebResult(name = RESULT_ELEMENT, targetNamespace = NAMESPACE_RESPONSE)
  ResponseType executeWs(RequestType wsRequest);

}
```